# When I try to include the chart.js and angular chartjs files, I get: ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I am working on an angularjs site - angular is already included.  We have code that loops through js scripts in a specific folder and adds them to a bundle, so the script references get emitted on the main page (we are using single page architecture).

I have not explicitly tried to invoke the code, it is currently just getting included, yet when I bring up my site, I now get the following js errors:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**

and it's happening here:
**var gulp = require('gulp'),**

I did not use bower to install - I just pulled the source and dropped the folders into the folder that gets parsed for emitting the js scripts.

**Is there something else I need to install?**

Comment: var gulp = require('gulp') - looks more like the server side NodeJS code, I thunk this is the problem

Comment: Yes, a coworker pointed out that's what it was, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

shershen, that is what I came to realize.

I removed all the misc files in the folder and just left the Chart.min.js and the angular-chart.min.js files and then I was good to go.